# Sequelize one-to-many association errors

Tags: sql, node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

I’m currently working on a new API which uses SequelizeJS with PostgreDB. I normally work with MongoDB and am having some trouble getting the associations working based on specific columns (not the standard id). I want to reduce how many database calls I make in common operations.

I have 3 tables named as follows: Sites, Buildings, Areas.
- Sites have many Buildings (Site: reference <->Building: siteReference)
- Buildings have many Areas (Building: Reference <-> Area: buildingReference)
- A building belongs to a site
- Areas belong to a Building

I have followed the Sequelize docs as best as I can (finding it a little difficult to understand the examples), and believed that the following would work (at this moment just sites<->buildings):

```
Sites.hasMany(Buildings, { as: 'relatedBuildings', targetKey: 'siteReference'});
Buildings.belongsTo(Sites, { as: 'parentSite', sourceKey: 'reference'});

// Query function
return mainDB.Sites
    .findAll({
        raw: true,
        include: [{
            model: mainDB.Buildings,
            as: 'relatedBuildings'
        }]
    })
    .then(dbRes => { console.log(dbRes));
    .catch(error => {console.log('ERROR', error.message)})
```

However, when I run the above code I receive the following errors:

```
First Error: relation "Sites" does not exist (note: the associations are stopping this table from being created)

Second Error: 
"status": 409,
            "message": "A database error occurred. Further details attached.",
            "value": {
                "name": "SequelizeDatabaseError",
                "parent": {
                    "name": "error",
                    "length": 110,
                    "severity": "ERROR",
                    "code": "42P01",
                    "position": "1678",
                    "file": "parse_relation.c",
                    "line": "1160",
                    "routine": "parserOpenTable",
                    "sql": "SELECT \"Sites\".\"id\", \"Sites\".\"reference\", \"Sites\".\"name\", \"Sites\".\"description\", \"Sites\".\"addressLine1\", \"Sites\".\"addressLine2\", \"Sites\".\"city\", \"Sites\".\"county\", \"Sites\".\"postcode\", \"Sites\".\"country\", \"Sites\".\"lat\", \"Sites\".\"long\", \"Sites\".\"type\", \"Sites\".\"companyReference\", \"Sites\".\"namedContactReference\", \"Sites\".\"status\", \"Sites\".\"created_at\", \"Sites\".\"updated_at\", \"relatedBuildings\".\"id\" AS \"relatedBuildings.id\", \"relatedBuildings\".\"reference\" AS \"relatedBuildings.reference\", \"relatedBuildings\".\"name\" AS \"relatedBuildings.name\", \"relatedBuildings\".\"description\" AS \"relatedBuildings.description\", \"relatedBuildings\".\"addressLine1\" AS \"relatedBuildings.addressLine1\", \"relatedBuildings\".\"addressLine2\" AS \"relatedBuildings.addressLine2\", \"relatedBuildings\".\"city\" AS \"relatedBuildings.city\", \"relatedBuildings\".\"county\" AS \"relatedBuildings.county\", \"relatedBuildings\".\"postcode\" AS \"relatedBuildings.postcode\", \"relatedBuildings\".\"country\" AS \"relatedBuildings.country\", \"relatedBuildings\".\"lat\" AS \"relatedBuildings.lat\", \"relatedBuildings\".\"long\" AS \"relatedBuildings.long\", \"relatedBuildings\".\"type\" AS \"relatedBuildings.type\", \"relatedBuildings\".\"siteReference\" AS \"relatedBuildings.siteReference\", \"relatedBuildings\".\"namedContactReference\" AS \"relatedBuildings.namedContactReference\", \"relatedBuildings\".\"status\" AS \"relatedBuildings.status\", \"relatedBuildings\".\"created_at\" AS \"relatedBuildings.created_at\", \"relatedBuildings\".\"updated_at\" AS \"relatedBuildings.updated_at\", \"relatedBuildings\".\"site_id\" AS \"relatedBuildings.site_id\", \"relatedBuildings\".\"related_buildings_id\" AS \"relatedBuildings.related_buildings_id\" FROM \"Sites\" AS \"Sites\" LEFT OUTER JOIN \"Buildings\" AS \"relatedBuildings\" ON \"Sites\".\"id\" = \"relatedBuildings\".\"site_id\";"
                },
                "original": {
                    "name": "error",
                    "length": 110,
                    "severity": "ERROR",
                    "code": "42P01",
                    "position": "1678",
                    "file": "parse_relation.c",
                    "line": "1160",
                    "routine": "parserOpenTable",
                    "sql": "SELECT \"Sites\".\"id\", \"Sites\".\"reference\", \"Sites\".\"name\", \"Sites\".\"description\", \"Sites\".\"addressLine1\", \"Sites\".\"addressLine2\", \"Sites\".\"city\", \"Sites\".\"county\", \"Sites\".\"postcode\", \"Sites\".\"country\", \"Sites\".\"lat\", \"Sites\".\"long\", \"Sites\".\"type\", \"Sites\".\"companyReference\", \"Sites\".\"namedContactReference\", \"Sites\".\"status\", \"Sites\".\"created_at\", \"Sites\".\"updated_at\", \"relatedBuildings\".\"id\" AS \"relatedBuildings.id\", \"relatedBuildings\".\"reference\" AS \"relatedBuildings.reference\", \"relatedBuildings\".\"name\" AS \"relatedBuildings.name\", \"relatedBuildings\".\"description\" AS \"relatedBuildings.description\", \"relatedBuildings\".\"addressLine1\" AS \"relatedBuildings.addressLine1\", \"relatedBuildings\".\"addressLine2\" AS \"relatedBuildings.addressLine2\", \"relatedBuildings\".\"city\" AS \"relatedBuildings.city\", \"relatedBuildings\".\"county\" AS \"relatedBuildings.county\", \"relatedBuildings\".\"postcode\" AS \"relatedBuildings.postcode\", \"relatedBuildings\".\"country\" AS \"relatedBuildings.country\", \"relatedBuildings\".\"lat\" AS \"relatedBuildings.lat\", \"relatedBuildings\".\"long\" AS \"relatedBuildings.long\", \"relatedBuildings\".\"type\" AS \"relatedBuildings.type\", \"relatedBuildings\".\"siteReference\" AS \"relatedBuildings.siteReference\", \"relatedBuildings\".\"namedContactReference\" AS \"relatedBuildings.namedContactReference\", \"relatedBuildings\".\"status\" AS \"relatedBuildings.status\", \"relatedBuildings\".\"created_at\" AS \"relatedBuildings.created_at\", \"relatedBuildings\".\"updated_at\" AS \"relatedBuildings.updated_at\", \"relatedBuildings\".\"site_id\" AS \"relatedBuildings.site_id\", \"relatedBuildings\".\"related_buildings_id\" AS \"relatedBuildings.related_buildings_id\" FROM \"Sites\" AS \"Sites\" LEFT OUTER JOIN \"Buildings\" AS \"relatedBuildings\" ON \"Sites\".\"id\" = \"relatedBuildings\".\"site_id\";"
                },
                "sql": "SELECT \"Sites\".\"id\", \"Sites\".\"reference\", \"Sites\".\"name\", \"Sites\".\"description\", \"Sites\".\"addressLine1\", \"Sites\".\"addressLine2\", \"Sites\".\"city\", \"Sites\".\"county\", \"Sites\".\"postcode\", \"Sites\".\"country\", \"Sites\".\"lat\", \"Sites\".\"long\", \"Sites\".\"type\", \"Sites\".\"companyReference\", \"Sites\".\"namedContactReference\", \"Sites\".\"status\", \"Sites\".\"created_at\", \"Sites\".\"updated_at\", \"relatedBuildings\".\"id\" AS \"relatedBuildings.id\", \"relatedBuildings\".\"reference\" AS \"relatedBuildings.reference\", \"relatedBuildings\".\"name\" AS \"relatedBuildings.name\", \"relatedBuildings\".\"description\" AS \"relatedBuildings.description\", \"relatedBuildings\".\"addressLine1\" AS \"relatedBuildings.addressLine1\", \"relatedBuildings\".\"addressLine2\" AS \"relatedBuildings.addressLine2\", \"relatedBuildings\".\"city\" AS \"relatedBuildings.city\", \"relatedBuildings\".\"county\" AS \"relatedBuildings.county\", \"relatedBuildings\".\"postcode\" AS \"relatedBuildings.postcode\", \"relatedBuildings\".\"country\" AS \"relatedBuildings.country\", \"relatedBuildings\".\"lat\" AS \"relatedBuildings.lat\", \"relatedBuildings\".\"long\" AS \"relatedBuildings.long\", \"relatedBuildings\".\"type\" AS \"relatedBuildings.type\", \"relatedBuildings\".\"siteReference\" AS \"relatedBuildings.siteReference\", \"relatedBuildings\".\"namedContactReference\" AS \"relatedBuildings.namedContactReference\", \"relatedBuildings\".\"status\" AS \"relatedBuildings.status\", \"relatedBuildings\".\"created_at\" AS \"relatedBuildings.created_at\", \"relatedBuildings\".\"updated_at\" AS \"relatedBuildings.updated_at\", \"relatedBuildings\".\"site_id\" AS \"relatedBuildings.site_id\", \"relatedBuildings\".\"related_buildings_id\" AS \"relatedBuildings.related_buildings_id\" FROM \"Sites\" AS \"Sites\" LEFT OUTER JOIN \"Buildings\" AS \"relatedBuildings\" ON \"Sites\".\"id\" = \"relatedBuildings\".\"site_id\";"
            }
```

Ultimately I am aiming to get an output as follows when I run a FindAll() on my Sites table:

```
Site
- Building
- - Area
- - Area
- Building
- - Area
- Building
- - Area
- - Area
- - Area
Site
- Building
- - Area
- - Area
- Building
- - Area
- - Area
Site
- Building
- - Area
- - Area
```

Where am I going wrong?

**UPDATE** - here are my models (note I formally define them elsewhere)

Sites

```
const Sites = {
    name: 'Sites',
    schema: {
        id: {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
            primaryKey: true,
            autoIncrement: true,
            allowNull: false
        },
        reference: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING(100),
            unique: true,
            allowNull: false
        },
        name: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING,
            allowNull: false
        },
        description: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING(512),
            allowNull: true
        },
        addressLine1: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING,
            allowNull: false
        },
        addressLine2: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING,
            allowNull: false
        },
        city: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING,
            allowNull: false
        },
        county: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING,
            allowNull: false
        },
        postcode: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING,
            allowNull: false
        },
        country: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING,
            allowNull: false
        },
        lat: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING,
            allowNull: false
        },
        long: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING,
            allowNull: false
        },
        type: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING,
            allowNull: false
        },
        companyReference: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING(100),
            allowNull: false
        },
        namedContactReference: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING(100),
            allowNull: true
        },
        status: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING(20),
            allowNull: false
        }
    },
    options: {
        underscored: true
    }
};

export default Sites;
```

Buildings

```
const Buildings = {
    name: 'Buildings',
    schema: {
        id: {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
            primaryKey: true,
            autoIncrement: true,
            allowNull: false
        },
        reference: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING(100),
            unique: true,
            allowNull: false
        },
        name: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING,
            allowNull: false
        },
        description: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING(256),
            unique: false,
            allowNull: true
        },
        addressLine1: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING,
            allowNull: false
        },
        addressLine2: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING,
            allowNull: false
        },
        city: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING,
            allowNull: false
        },
        county: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING,
            allowNull: false
        },
        postcode: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING,
            allowNull: false
        },
        country: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING,
            allowNull: false
        },
        lat: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING,
            allowNull: false
        },
        long: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING,
            allowNull: false
        },
        type: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING,
            allowNull: false
        },
        siteReference: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING(100),
            allowNull: false
        },
        namedContactReference: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING(100),
            allowNull: true
        },
        status: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING(20),
            allowNull: false
        }
    },
    options: { underscored: true }
};
export default Buildings;
```

Areas

```
const Areas = {
    name: 'Areas',
    schema: {
        id: {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
            primaryKey: true,
            autoIncrement: true,
            allowNull: false
        },
        reference: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING(100),
            unique: true,
            allowNull: false
        },
        buildingReference: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING(100),
            unique: false,
            allowNull: false
        },
        panelReference: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING(100),
            unique: false,
            allowNull: false
        },
        name: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING(128),
            unique: false,
            allowNull: false
        },
        description: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING(512),
            allowNull: true
        },
        drawingReference: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING(100),
            unique: false,
            allowNull: false
        },
        status: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING(10),
            allowNull: false
        }
    },
    options: { underscored: true }
};
export default Areas;
```

Comment: can you paste the complete model files, It can be many things which might go wrong.Do the tables exsists or have you run the sync on migrate

Comment: @KevalGohil sure I will post them when I’m back at my computer later today. Currently I have force:true on sync as I’m using seed data to prefill with test content. Everything is working until I start coding in the associations!

Comment: @KevalGohil models added

Answer (score 0):

Did you set the associations in the models?

> Please refer to the [Sequelize docs](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/associations.html) at the section [belongs-to-many-associations](/questions/tagged/belongs-to-many-associations)

#### Example

If I understand your problem correctly you would like to set up a many-to-many relation in other words a n:m.

Using [sequelize](/questions/tagged/sequelize) you can do that by setting a relation on both models to

`belongsToMany(Model,{through: 'tableNameYouWant'});`

---

```
// In Your Site Model
Sites.belongsToMany(Buildings, {through: 'SiteBuildings'});

// In your Building Model
Buildings.belongsToMany(Sites, {through: 'SiteBuildings'});

// In your Area Model
Areas.belongsTo(Buildings)
```

Let me know if that helped fixing your problem!

Comment: I do my associations at the point I define each model. I define my schema, import it into a model definition and then define them all at once. I then run a function containing all of these associations before forcefully syncing. They are being applied as I see them in Postico. Maybe I will scrap this implementation and use the one described in the docs.

Comment: So I changed the through: 'SiteBuildings' to be my table names, however I get: 'SequelizeAssociationError: You have used the alias Buildings in two separate associations. Aliased associations must have unique aliases.'. 

I also tried including sourceKey and targetKey, with no further luck.

Comment: @user5156141 Okey so if you'll have an AssociationError it basically means that: You've already used the as 'Buildings' Association somewhere else. That's not possible with Sequelize. Can you add me to your github project? I can have a look if you would like.

Comment: I haven't intentionally named anything Buildings, other than my database table. I've got a HasMany working with my Sites containing Buildings.. Just need to figure out how to get areas with those buildings and a company with each site!

Comment: I need to see the code in depth mate. Can you add me to the github @user5156141

Comment: I’m not able to add you to the main project. I’ll fork it and remove all the sensitive stuff, which I’ll be able to add you to. Will do this ASAP. So far I’ve managed to get the hasMany working (aliases don’t work though), but no BelongsTo, belongsToMany or hasOne.

Comment: sure, let me know whenever I can help.